# How do I continue to read data from ReadAsync after I start processing the data?

Tags: c#, networkstream

I am new here and by no means an expert at c# programming.

I am writing an application that connects to a device over TCP.  It sends the device a command and the device responds.  Sometimes The device will send another message after it has responded to my command.  For example if I say "Read Tag" It will respond with the tag value "Tag: abcdefg".  But sometimes, after a couple of hundred milliseconds, it will respond with something like "Buffer Low: 14" telling me the size of its buffer.

Here is how I am currently receiving data:

```
            public Task<string> ReceiveDataAsync()
    {
        receiveBuffer = new byte[receiveBufferSize];
        Task<int> streamTask = _networkstream.ReadAsync(receiveBuffer, 0, receiveBufferSize);
        // Since the read is async and data arrival is unknown, the event
        // must sit around until there is something to be raised.
        var resultTask = streamTask.ContinueWith<String>(antecedent =>
        {
            Array.Resize(ref receiveBuffer, streamTask.Result);  // resize the result to the size of the data that was returned
            var result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBuffer);
            OnDataReceived(new TCPEventArgs(result));
            return result;
        });
        return resultTask;
    }
```

I am confused about reading the network stream.  When I use the ReadAsync method, and then I get something back, how do I handle the delay?  In my mind, I get the first response of the tag data, then I start to work on that task.  Even though I work on the task ".ContinueWith" will my stream continue to receive data?  Will the task automatically go back and process more data as it comes in the stream?  Do I need to call the ReceiveDataAsync method every time I think some data should be arriving or will it remain open until Dispose of the stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to call `ReceiveDataAsync` repeatedly, usually call it in callback of `ContinueWith`, or just put it in a loop if you use `async`/`await`, so that you read some data, process it and then go back to read (or wait) the next bytes.

Like this:

```
private static void OnContinuationAction(Task<string> text)
{
    Console.WriteLine(text);
    ReceiveDataAsync().ContinueWith(OnContinuationAction);
}

...

ReceiveDataAsync().ContinueWith(OnContinuationAction);
```

Or with `async`/`await`:

```
private async void ReceiveDataContinuously()
{
    while(true)
    {
        var text = await ReceiveDataAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

If you don't call `ReadAsync` on the stream repeatedly, as long as the underlying TCP connection is open it will continue receiving data into the buffer, but your program cannot get them.